# Query APM based on request headers

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, apm

Referencing to the [configuration over capturing headers with APM](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/dotnet/current/config-http.html#config-capture-headers) which is set to `true` by default in one of our Spring Boot application. I am curious to understand if there is also a follow up configuration to make these help us query or visualise over our request patterns on APM?

Use Case - I have a request header
`X-Tenant-Id` and I want to visualise the distribution percentage per tenant using this as a means.

At present, I am unable to perform this with a message

> Unindexed fields or ignored values cannot be searched

An alternate that I could think of would be to intercept request at our application and then updating the current transaction of APM, but that's unintuitive and could be prone to some performance impact in our application.

Comment: The most likely issue is because the `http.response.headers` object has `enabled: false` in the mapping. Can you get the mapping of your APM index and share it in your question: `GET logs-apm*/_mapping/field/http.reponse.headers`. And if you don't have such a field in your mapping, it might be because `dynamic` is set to false.

Comment: @Val True, fetching the `/_mapping` for the index `apm-*` returns  `{"type":object, "enabled":false}`. Also, I can observe that the parameter at `"http"` properties is set to `"dynamic":false`. So, is there a config/way to enable this?

Comment: Thought so! You need to modify the related index template (called something like `logs-apm...`) and then roll over your apm index

Comment: @Val Rollovers, if you meant for the consideration of size, are already in place based on date e.g `apm-7.17.8-metric-2023.10.31` in my current index for metric collection. Can you throw more light on what configuration over the index template are you referring to? Hoping that it could answer how to solve the problem and would be a long-term solution considering rollovers and dynamic mapping creation.

Comment: Can you retrieve the index template on which the `apm-*-metric-*` indexes are based on and share it in your question?

Comment: I might recommend you to use LocalThread to be stored the tenant ID, and use it when you need, but the approach that you commented having a pre-filter, I didn't see your specific case, but when handling a value of "TenantID" depends on the context is valuable to keep in a safe store like I commented.